# .NET, ASP.NET 'DropYear' has a SelectedValue which is invalid?

Tags: asp.net, .net

This error is occurring with Insite Creation CMS when new content is added to the Latest News section of the site (it does not occur with other parts of the website). I searched from 'DropYear' online and via Stackoverflow without success. Anyone know how I might resolve the error? (I'm not a programmer).

'dropYear' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'dropYear' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

**Source Error:**

```
Line 1165:        dropMonth.SelectedValue = Month(Me.InsitePage.display_date.AddHours(Me.SiteSetting.TimeOffset))
Line 1166:        dropDay.SelectedValue = Day(Me.InsitePage.display_date.AddHours(Me.SiteSetting.TimeOffset))
Line 1167:        dropYear.SelectedValue = Year(Me.InsitePage.display_date.AddHours(Me.SiteSetting.TimeOffset))
Line 1168:
Line 1169:        txtBody.Text = Me.InsitePage.content_body
```

**Source File:** `C:\HostingSpaces\rdapilba\rdapilbara.org.au\wwwroot\systems\authoring.ascx.vb    Line: 1167`

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'dropYear' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.set_SelectedValue(String value) +9703262
   systems_authoring.PrepareEditPage() in C:\HostingSpaces\rdapilba\rdapilbara.org.au\wwwroot\systems\authoring.ascx.vb:1167
   systems_authoring.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\HostingSpaces\rdapilba\rdapilbara.org.au\wwwroot\systems\authoring.ascx.vb:46
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

Thank you in advance. Kind regards Alan

Comment: You trying to assign a value to the dropdown which is not in the dropdown's items collection.

Comment: can you post your aspx code of dropdown?

Comment: Thank you Sankar, I really appreciate you responding. As it turns out it is a bug in the CMS which the developer has kindly offered to fix.